# Jfrog Artifactory Publish Build Info Failure

Tags: artifactory, publish, jfrog-cli

After successfully building my image using the following command (Jfrog CLI + Openshift CLI):

```
jf rt oc start-build <BuildConfig name> --server-id=<JFrog CLI config server ID> --repo=<Docker repository name> --build-name=<to be saved in the build-info> --build-number=<to be saved in the build-info>
```

When I try to publish the build info, I receive the following permission error, even though I'm using a highly privileged user within Artifactory. Does anyone know which permissions are required for a user to be able to publish build info and how to change them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A 403 forbidden error indicates that a user that has been configured in JFrog CLI does not have enough permissions to deploy builds.
In order to deploy a build the user should have deploy permissions. We can enable this option by following the below steps:-

1. Navigate to Administration -> User Management, and select the user configured for JFrog CLI.
2. In the User Permission section select - **builds**, and click on the Permission target(ex:- Anything).
3. In this, select the User(configured in CLI) under the Users section.
4. Select the Users build and enable the 'deploy' permissions and save it. Refer to this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ6Ua.png) .
   Now try to publish the builds again, it will work.

For more information on Permissions refer to this [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions#Permissions-Builds).